# Level Set Advection with Extension Velocity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

We're studying the following system of PDEs for a scalar function $F(x, t)$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  The function $F(\cdot, t)$ is a level set function for a time-dependent family of surfaces $S_t := \{ x : F(x, t) = 0 \}$.  The idea is that $S_t$ moves by some curvature-driven flow.  Thus there is a "speed function" $v : S_t \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which gives the normal component of the velocity of the surface as it moves. For example, $v(x, t)$ could be the mean curvature of $S_t$ at $x$.

The PDE which governs this situation is

\begin{gather*}
\dot F + V \|\nabla F\| = 0 \\
F(\cdot, t=0) = \mbox{given}
\end{gather*}

where $V$ is some extension of $v$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  There are many ways to extend $v$.  For example, if $v(x, t)$ is the mean curvature of $S_t$ at $x$, then $V(x, t)$ could be the mean curvature of whatever level set of $F(\cdot ,t)$ that $x$ belongs to.  But most of these extension procedures do not preserve an important normalization of $F$ that we'd like to keep.  That is, we would like to enforce that $F(\cdot, t)$ is always the "signed distance function" of $S_t$ for all time.  In other words, we'd like to maintain $\| \nabla F(x, t) \| = 1$ for all a.e. $x$ and all $t$.  This can be achieved (at least formally) if we also impose the condition

\begin{gather*}
< \nabla F, \nabla V > = 0 \mbox{ at each } t \\
V(\cdot, t) \mbox{ on } S_t \mbox{ equals } v(\cdot, t)
\end{gather*}

So all in all, we have an interesting system of equations...

Given:

$F_0$ an initial level set function and a procedure for generating a speed function $v$ from a surface $S$

Solve:
\begin{gather*}
\dot F + V \|\nabla F\| = 0 \\
%
< \nabla F, \nabla V > = 0 \\
%
V(x, t) \mbox{ equals } v(x) \mbox{ constructed from the surface } S_t := \{ x : F(x, t) = 0 \} \mbox{ and } x \in S_t \\
%
F(\cdot, t=0) = F_0
\end{gather*}

This system of equations is somewhat different from the usual curvature flow formulation for a level set function, because in the usual setting the normalization condition "$F = $ signed distance function" is not imposed.  Imposing this condition seems like a good idea because it takes away an unwanted degeneracy (makes a canonical choice for the level set function of the moving surface) but it has the drawback of taking us away from the realm of scalar Hamilton-Jacobi equations (I think).

I am interested in understanding existence and regularity results for this system of equations. In the process, I'd like to understand the requirements on the procedure "Surface $\rightarrow$ speed function."  I'm also interested in the convergence of the following discretization scheme:

1) Given $F$ and $V$, use standard procedures (upwinding, etc.) to compute one time step of the equation $\dot F + V \|\nabla F\| = 0$.  This gives us a new $F$.

2) Compute the new surface $F=0$ and the new $v$ on the new surface.

3) Solve $< \nabla F, V > = 0$ with $V = v$ on the new surface by standard procedures. This gives us a new $V$.

4) Go to (1) and repeat.

Note that the above procedure is what you get when you put the "Level Set Method" together with the Extension Velocity procedure of Sethian + Adalsteinsson. This dates back to the early 2000s.  But I am not an expert in these kinds PDE and would like to know what is out there in the literature (or from the true experts themselves!) concerning the analytical questions above.

Many thanks for your help.

Adrian Butscher

Comment: Corrected a typo -- changed $V$ to $\nabla V$ in the obvious places.  Thanks to Peter Frolkovic for pointing that out!